# python function .json(): No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, django

the function looks like this:

```
import requests
import json
def parse(s):
    r = requests.post('http://166.111.139.15:9000/?properties%3d%7b%22annotators%22%3a%22tokenize%2cssplit%2cpos%2clemma%2cparse%22%2c%22outputFormat%22%3a%22json%22%7d%0a', data=s)
    return r.json()

print parse("I am a student")
```

And when I use it in Django, the web page shows:
"No JSON object could be decoded".Why?

Comment: Try using `return r.content()`

Answer (score 3):

`No JSON object could be decoded` is an exception message raised at `r.json()`. If your response is not a valid json object you can still retrieve it with `r.text`. Even if you are sure your response is always a valid json object, you should still check whether server returned a success code. If there's an internal server error (code 500), you won't get a valid json response!

```
import requests

def parse(s)
    r = requests.post('http://someserver.com', data=s)
    if r.status_code !== 200:
        return "There was a problem: {} !".format(r.text)
    return r.json()
```

Comment: I like to use [`r.raise_for_status()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status)